# Linux Mint - Desktop Freezes

Tags: linux, linux-mint, freeze

I am running the latest Linux Mint on a desktop machine and I constantly experience system freezes such as:

- No input from keyboard
- Partially working mouse (i.e. the cursor moves, but there is no right-click, or the right click works partially over the "Start" menu, but I cannot select anything)
- No input at all

Usually I can solve this by doing a hard-reboot. Sometimes I can ssh from another machine and reboot it, but most of the times ssh does not work either.

It may be a coincidence, but in most of the times when the system freezes I have VVirtualBox running. However, I had VMWare Player before and it was acting the same, so I switched to VirtualBox hoping it will get fixed.

I have tried the "nomodeset" option, but then my second screen is not detected (the system only sees one display and it sees my system as a laptop).

Here are my system details:

inxi -Fx

```
System:    Host: my.machine.name Kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) 
           Desktop: Cinnamon 2.6.13  Distro: Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
Machine:   System: Dell product: OptiPlex 3010 version: 01
           Mobo: Dell model: 042P49 version: A01 Bios: Dell version: A09 date: 01/31/2013
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-3470 CPU (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 25541.2 
           Clock Speeds: 1: 1915.875 MHz 2: 3060.625 MHz 3: 1923.250 MHz 4: 2718.375 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0 
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV370 [Radeon X600/X600 SE] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
           X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: ati,radeon,intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@60.0hz, 1920x1080@60.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Ivybridge Desktop GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card: Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture ver: k3.16.0-38-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
           driver: r8169 ver: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: eth0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: a4:1f:72:77:aa:1c
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1512.3GB (15.9% used) 1: id: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD10EZEX size: 1000.2GB temp: 34C 
           2: id: /dev/sdb model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 512.1GB temp: 0C 
Partition: ID: / size: 63G used: 37G (63%) fs: ext4 ID: /home size: 188G used: 38G (22%) fs: ext4 
RAID:      No RAID devices detected - /proc/mdstat and md_mod kernel raid module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C 
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A 
Info:      Processes: 208 Uptime: 13 min Memory: 1255.7/11919.4MB Runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.8.4 
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.11) inxi: 1.9.17
```

Comment: Does it freeze when not running a virtual machine? And/Or when running a different WM, tried xfwm from xfce, mate. etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try:

1. Don't run a virtual machine for a while and see if it still freezes. Could be a problem with the VM, maybe some settings that could make it more stable (maybe hardware acceleration, etc)
2. Try a different window manager (WM). Cinnamon may look nice, but I've found xfce's wm (xfwm) to be more stable. Same for compiz in the past, it was awesome having windows "burn" away, but crashing every few hours was not so awesome. You can install multiple desktop environments, and I think just their window managers too (may not be as simple)

   The XFCE window manager's package name is currently `xfwm4`, so installing it with
   `sudo apt-get install xfwm4`
   should work... Other window managers include (in alphabetical order, definitely NOT a complete list):

   - `e17` - Enlightenment DR17
   - `fluxbox`
   - `gnome-shell`
   - `icewm` - wonderful Win95-OS/2-Motif-like window manager
   - `kde-window-manager` - K window manager (KWin)
   - `lxde` - didn't find just the window manager entry
   - `openbox` - standards-compliant, fast, light-weight and extensible window manager

   There's also MATE & a lot of others, probably some Ubuntu specific Unity stuff available too.

   This Q has some good overviews: https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available
3. Worthwhile to test RAM with memtest too.